# extension of certain invariant distributions

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field. Let $G=F^\times$ and $X=F^2-\{(0,0)\}$. Let $G$ acts on $X$ by $a.(x,y)=(ax,ay),a\in F^\times, (x,y)\in X$. Let $U=\{(x,y)\in X, xy\ne 0\}$.

$\textbf{Question 1}$: Is there a $G$-invariant distribution $T$ on $X$ such that the restriction of $T$ to $U$ is non-zero?

Here is one example in my mind that illustrates there might not exist such $T$ in Question 1. Consider the multiplicative action of $F^\times$ on $F$, and let $U=\{x\in F,x\ne 0\}$, which is an open subset of $U$. Then by Tate's thesis, there is no $F^\times$-invariant distribution $T$ on $F$ such that $T|_U$ is non-zero. In fact, the only $F^\times$-invariant distribution on $F$ is the Dirac measure.

If Question 1 DOES have an affirmative answer, then here is

$\textbf{Question 2}$: Let $\psi$ be a non-trivial additive character of $F$ and let $\mu=\psi(y/x)d^*xd^*y$, viewed as a measure on $U$. It is clear that $\mu$ is $G$-invariant. Is there a $G$-invariant distribution on $X$ such that $T|_U=\mu$?

Here is another similar question

$\textbf{Question 3}$: Let $G=F^\times \times F^\times,X=F^3-\{0\}$ and $U=(F^\times)^3$. Let $G$ act on $X$ by $(a,b).(x,y,z)=(ax,by,abz)$. Is there a $G$-invariant distribution $T$ on $X$ such that $T|_U$ is nontrivial? If such $T$ exists, what can we say about $Supp(T|_U)$?

### Edits:

Many thanks to @paulgarrett to give an affirmative answer to $\textbf{Question 1}$. There does exist $G$-invariant distribution $T$ such that $T|_U$ is non-zero. For example, take $T$ as $$<T,\varphi>=\int_{F^\times}\varphi(\alpha,\alpha)d^*\alpha,\varphi\in S(X).$$

Here is a variant of Question 1.

$\textbf{Question 1'}$: Let $Y=F^2$ and $G=F^\times$ act on $Y$ by $a.(x,y)=(ax,ay).$ Is there a distribution $T\in S^*(Y)^G$ such that $Supp(T|_U)=U$? Here $U=(F^\times)^2\subset Y$.

I am sorry that I also asked the same question in mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279930/non-existence-of-certain-invariant-distributions-on-p-adic-spaces , because I thought it might draw more attention there. If it is not permitted, I will delete one.

Thanks.

Comment: But $(0,1)$ is still in $X$. The measure $\mu$ is not well-defined because of this. It's just like you cannot take integral $\int_F \phi(x)d^*x$ for $\phi\in S(F)$ because $\phi$ needn't be zero at $0$.

Comment: Ok, because you said $X = F^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$ while $\mu$ gives a distribution on $U = F^* \times F^*$. Then why do you expect there is another $F^\times$ invariant "distribution" such that $T|_U = \mu$ ? Now I interpret your question as if there is some sort of principal value allowing to extend distributions at singular points

Comment: I think Tate's thesis says that the only $F^\times$-invariant distribution on $F$ is the Dirac measure, which restricts to 0 on $F^\times$. There is an exact sequence, $0\rightarrow Hom_{F^\times}(S(0),\textbf{C})\rightarrow Hom_{F^\times}(S(F),\textbf{C})\rightarrow Hom_{F^\times}(S(F^\times),\textbf{C})$, while Tate's thesis says that $dim Hom_{F^\times}(S(F),\textbf{C})=1$. Here, $S(F)$ is the space of Bruhat-Schwartz functions on $F$.

Comment: Are the distributions $\varphi\to \int_{F^\times} \varphi(\alpha\cdot (x_o,y_o)\;d\alpha$ (with multiplicative Haar measure) not the sort of thing you want? Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @paulgarrett I am sorry, how do you choose $x_0,y_0$ such that $\int_{F^\times}\varphi(\alpha x_0,\alpha y_0)d^*\alpha$ is well-defined for all $\varphi\in S(X)$, and $\varphi\mapsto \int_{F^\times}\varphi(\alpha x_0,\alpha y_0)d^*\alpha$ is not trivial on $S(U)$?

Comment: @QingZhang, any $(x_o,y_o)$ in $U$ succeeds: every $\varphi\in S(X)$ is supported away from $(0,0)$, so the integral exists. A Schwartz/test function identically $1$ on a small nbd of $(x_o,y_o)$ gives a non-zero value.

Comment: @paulgarrett Let's take $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$ and $\varphi(x,y)=\chi_{R}(x)\chi_{R^*}(y)$, where $R$ is the ring of integers, $R^*$ is set of units of $R$, and $\chi_{R}$ (resp. $\chi_{R^*}$) denotes the characteristic function of $R\subset F$ (resp. $R^*\subset F$) . Then $\varphi(0,0)=\chi_R(0)\chi_{R^*}(0)=0$ because $0\notin R^*$. Is $\int_X \varphi(\alpha,\alpha)d^*\alpha$ convergent? I doubt it.

Comment: @QingZhang, but I don't propose integrating over the whole $X$, only along the "ray" parametrized by $(x_o,y_o)$.

Comment: @paulgarrett I misunderstood your point. It seems that's correct. How about the second question?